# BigQuery: flatten two repeated columns

Tags: google-bigquery

I am currently working with a very simple table on BigQuery and each row has two repeated columns `class_numbers` `[REPEATED INTEGER]` and `class_descriptions` `[REPEATED STRING]`, both these repeated properties have the same length and there is a correspondence on the index of each, eg: for a given record `class_numbers[1]` description will be on `class_descriptions[1]`.

What I need to do is to basically transform these two repeated fields in a flat table, keeping the correspondence between both columns, how can I achieve that?

Using a `SELECT class_numbers, class_descriptions FROM test.mytable` using standard SQL returns the same table (with repeated fields) and doing the same on legacy SQL throws an error "Cannot output multiple independently repeated fields at the same time.".

How can I achieve the desired result?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using standard SQL, you can use `UNNEST(...) WITH OFFSET`. For example,

```
SELECT
  class_number,
  class_descriptions[OFFSET(off)] AS class_description
FROM MyTable,
  UNNEST(class_numbers) AS class_number WITH OFFSET off;
```

Comment: maybe `class_number` should be `class_number[offset(off)]` as well to give the flattened result the OP wants (not sure)

Comment: `class_number` is the alias for the result of the `UNNEST(class_numbers)` and refers to a particular element of that array. [The documentation has more about `UNNEST`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest).

Comment: oh that's right! I solved in a different way and got an `array` as the result.

Comment: Thanks Elliott! That did exactly what I need!

Comment: This works for me but my two columns are different length so I get the error `Array index 6 is out bounds (overflow)`. If I switch the ordering it compiles but I lose the 3 rows of data. This is correct because when I look at the standard BigQuery result there are 6 rows in the first repeated column and then 3 in the second. For my data, this difference in index will vary throughout. How would I make it to just show `null` for the extra 3 rows in the second repeated column? So that I can have the entire thing unnested.

Answer (score 1):

Below is version for BigQuery Legacy SQL

```
SELECT 
  class_number, 
  class_description
FROM (
    SELECT 
      class_number, 
      number_pos, 
      class_descriptions AS class_description, 
      POSITION(class_descriptions) AS description_pos 
    FROM FLATTEN((
        SELECT 
          class_numbers AS class_number, 
          POSITION(class_numbers) AS number_pos, 
          class_descriptions 
        FROM YourTable
    ), class_numbers)
)
WHERE number_pos = description_pos
```