# Count and percentage of same strings within two groups with join

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I have three tables in Google Bigquery:

**t1**) *ID1, ID2*

**t2**) *ID1, Keywords* (500.000 rows)

**t3**) *ID2, Keywords* (3 million rows)

The observations of *ID1* have been matched/linked with observations in *ID2*, each observation has a number of keywords.

I want to know about the overlap in keywords between the matched *ID1*'s and *ID2*'s.

**t1**
`┌─────────────┐
│ ID1  │ ID2  │
├──────┼──────┤
│ 1    │ A    │
│ 1    │ B    │
│ 1    │ C    │
│ 1    │ D    │
│ 2    │ E    │
│ 2    │ F    │
│ 2    │ G    │
│ 2    │ H    │
│ 3    │ I    │
│ 3    │ J    │
│ 3    │ K    │
│ 3    │ L    │
│ 4    │ M    │
│ 4    │ N    │
│ 4    │ O    │
│ 4    │ P    │`

**t2**

`┌──────────────────────┐
│      TABLE 2         │
├──────────────────────┤
│ ID1     │ KEYWORD    │
│ 1       │ KEYWORD 1  │
│ 1       │ KEYWORD 2  │
│ 1       │ KEYWORD 3  │
│ 1       │ KEYWORD 4  │
│ 2       │ KEYWORD 2  │
│ 2       │ KEYWORD 3  │
│ 2       │ KEYWORD 6  │
│ 2       │ KEYWORD 8  │
│ 3       │ KEYWORD 10 │
│ 3       │ KEYWORD 64 │
│ 3       │ KEYWORD 42 │
│ 3       │ KEYWORD 39 │
│ 4       │ KEYWORD 18 │
│ 4       │ KEYWORD 33 │
│ 4       │ KEYWORD 52 │
│ 4       │ KEYWORD 24 │
└─────────┴────────────┘`

`t3
┌───────────────────────┐
│      TABLE 3          │
├───────────────────────┤
│ ID2     │ KEYWORD     │
│ A       │ KEYWORD 1   │
│ A       │ KEYWORD 2   │
│ A       │ KEYWORD 54  │
│ A       │ KEYWORD 34  │
│ B       │ KEYWORD 32  │
│ B       │ KEYWORD 876 │
│ B       │ KEYWORD 632 │
│ B       │ KEYWORD 2   │
│ K       │ KEYWORD 53  │
│ K       │ KEYWORD 43  │
│ K       │ KEYWORD 10  │
│ K       │ KEYWORD 64  │
│ P       │ KEYWORD 56  │
│ P       │ KEYWORD 44  │
│ P       │ KEYWORD 322 │
│ P       │ KEYWORD 99  │
└─────────┴─────────────┘`

As the tables show, *ID1* (1) is matched to *ID2* (A). Both *ID1* and *ID2* have a *KEYWORD 1* and *KEYWORD 2*, so there's a total of 2 keywords that overlap between both matched observations, which in this case (as *ID1* (A) has 4 keywords total) is 50% overlap. 
I am looking to make the following table, where every row in **t1** gets additional columns MATCH COUNT and MATCH PERCENTAGE.

`┌───────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ RESULT                                        │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ ID     │ ID2 │ MATCH COUNT │ MATCH PERCENTAGE │
│ 1      │ A   │ 2           │ 50%              │
│ 1      │ B   │ 1           │ 25%              │
│(...)   │(...)│ (...)       │ (...)            │ 
│ 3      │ K   │ 2           │ 50%              │
│ 4      │ P   │ 0           │ 0%               │
└────────┴─────┴─────────────┴──────────────────┘`

I know it is good etiquette to show what I've already done, but honestly this one is way over my head and I don't even know where to start. I am hoping that somebody can get me into the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `join` and `group by`:

```
select t1.id1, t2.id2
       count(t3.keyword) as num_matches,
       count(t3.keyword) / count(*) as proportion_matches
from t1 left join
     t2
     on t1.id1 = t2.id1 left join
     t3
     on t1.id2 = t3.id2 and
        t2.keyword = t3.keyword
group by t1.id1, t2.id2;
```

This assumes that the keywords are unique for each id.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try it out and let you know.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I've tried the code and it should work. However, I've discovered that the Keyword columns I have in tables t2 and t3 are set up as ARRAY<STRING>. So ID1 has a row that contains multiple Keyword rows. This causes bigquery to reply with "Error: Equality is not defined for arguments of type ARRAY<STRING> ". Do you know a way around this? Google is not helping me a lot.

Comment: Nevermind, I've improved my Googling and for future readers, this is how you turn ARRAY<STRING> into STRING: overwrite the table with a line 
[ UNNEST(keyword) AS keyword WITH OFFSET off;  ] see also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41120792/bigquery-flatten-two-repeated-columns

Answer (score 0):

I think it is solution:

```
select Id1, Id2, Sum(Match) Match, Sum(Match) / Sum(Total) as Perc
from (
    select t2.Id1, t2.Id2, Decode(t1.Keyword, t3.Keyword, 1, 0) Match, 1 Total
    from t2
         inner join t1 on (t2.Id1 = t1.Id1)
         inner join t3 on (t2.Id2 = t3.Id2)
)
group by Id1, Id2
```

if you don't have function Decode you can use case:

```
case when t1.Keyword = t3.Keyword then 1 else 0 end
```

Easier:

```
select t1.Id1, t1.Id2, Sum(case when t2.Keyword = t3.Keyword then 1 else 0 end) Match, Sum(case when t2.Keyword = t3.Keyword then 1 else 0 end) / Count(1) Perc
from t2
     inner join t1 on (t2.Id1 = t1.Id1)
    inner join t3 on (t1.Id2 = t3.Id2)
group by t1.Id1, t1.Id2
```

Google have function CountIf, you can use also:

```
select t1.Id1, t1.Id2, CountIf(t2.Keyword = t3.Keyword) Match, CountIf(t2.Keyword = t3.Keyword) / Count(1) Perc
from t2
     inner join t1 on (t2.Id1 = t1.Id1)
    inner join t3 on (t1.Id2 = t3.Id2)
group by t1.Id1, t1.Id2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try it out and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT t1.id1, t1.id2, 
  COUNTIF(t2.keyword = t3.keyword) match_count,
  COUNTIF(t2.keyword = t3.keyword) / COUNT(DISTINCT t2.keyword) match_percentage
FROM t2 CROSS JOIN t3
JOIN t1 ON t1.id1 = t2.id1 AND t1.id2 = t3.id2
GROUP BY t1.id1, t1.id2
-- ORDER BY t1.id1, t1.id2
```

with result as below

```
Row id1 id2 match_count match_percentage     
1   1   A   2           0.5  
2   1   B   1           0.25     
3   3   K   2           0.5  
4   4   P   0           0.0
```

Comment: Hey, I did try your version after using Gordon's. The issue I have with your version is that the output only selects around 5000 rows whereas t1 has 3.5 million rows. No idea why it does that.

Comment: It does this because of group by as per your question, so 3.5M are grouped into 5K which makes sense to me unless I am missing something

Comment: Well, lets say t1 has an ID1 that is matched to 4 different ID2s. I want to know the overlap in keywords between 1-1, 1-2, 1-3 and 1-4 in seperate rows.

Comment: The answer I posted  is perfectly (I think so) answers your original question. If you have new question - please post it :o). Meantime feel free to vote up and accept if applicable!