# BigQuery record of repeated fields

Tags: nested, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Bigquery table with (what is conceptually) a field containing repeated record.

However, this field is stored as a record of repeated fields. This is either caused by the export from AppEngine DataStore (using Mache), or by the representation of the data (using Objectify 3); I don't know.

So what I have is a field (`exercises`) that looks like this:

```
exercises           RECORD  NULLABLE    exercises
exercises.id        INTEGER REPEATED    id
exercises.weight    FLOAT   REPEATED    weight
exercises.duration  STRING  REPEATED    duration
```

instead of

```
exercises           RECORD  REPEATED    exercises
exercises.id        INTEGER NULLABLE    id
exercises.weight    FLOAT   NULLABLE    weight
exercises.duration  STRING  NULLABLE    duration
```

The latter can be queried easily using `FLATTEN` (legacy SQL) or `UNNEST` (standard SQL). However, with the schema I have now, I seem to be stuck.
I guess I would have to to transpose the `exercises` field in some way, from a records of arrays to an array of records.
The sub-fields of `exercises` always have the same length, so that should not be a problem.

How can I query and select this field?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried `UNNEST WITH OFFSET`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41120792/bigquery-flatten-two-repeated-columns):

```
SELECT
  exerciseId, exofs,
  exercises.weight[OFFSET(exofs)] AS exerciseWeight,
  exercises.duration[OFFSET(exofs)] AS exerciseDuration
FROM Session, UNNEST(exercises.id) AS exerciseId WITH OFFSET exofs
```

This works! This feature is only available in standard SQL. The `FLATTEN` in legacy SQL does not support `WITH OFFSET`.