# BigQuery: flatten multiple repeated columns of different length

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-firebase

I have followed the answers given to this question: [BigQuery: flatten two repeated columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41120792/bigquery-flatten-two-repeated-columns) but it doesn't quite work although it's the closest to what I'm looking for.

---

I have data being sent from Google Analytics to Google BigQuery from an app. I have 10 repeated columns:

- `event_params [RECORD REPEATED]`
- `user_properties [RECORD REPEATED]`
- `user_ltv [RECORD NULLABLE]`
- `device [RECORD NULLABLE]`
- `geo [RECORD NULLABLE]`
- `app_info [RECORD NULLABLE]`
- `traffic_source [RECORD NULLABLE]`
- `event_dimensions [RECORD NULLABLE]`
- `ecommerce [RECORD NULLABLE]`
- `items [RECORD REPEATED]`

Whenever there is a new event, there will be an:

- `event_date`
- `event_timestamp`
- `event_name`

for each row. These repeated properties can have different lengths for each event and there is a correspondence on the index of the event.

Below is a snapshot of just the first two repeated columns `event_params` and `user_properties` along with what I would want to generate with these two columns and the others if needed:

[image: Image of BigQuery default table]

Here we see that `event_params` has length 7 and `user_properties` has length 4. When I run the following code:

```sql
-- standardSQL
SELECT
    event_name, event_params,
    user_properties[OFFSET(off)] AS user_properties
FROM
    `yepic-2021.analytics_264796885.events_intraday_*`,
    UNNEST(event_params) AS event_params WITH OFFSET off
ORDER BY
    event_timestamp DESC
LIMIT 50
```

but this results in the error:

`Array index 4 is out of bounds (overflow)`

This makes sense because they are not the same length. So my thought was that if anyone knows how to add `null` to all the other columns until their length is equal to which ever column is has the longest length then this would produce the fully flattened output that I want.

This is an example of not what I want where there's an explosion of duplicates by flattening on the already flattened table:

```sql
-- standardSQL
SELECT
    event_name, event_params, user_properties
FROM
    `yepic-2021.analytics_264796885.events_intraday_*`,
    UNNEST(event_params) AS event_params,
    UNNEST(user_properties) AS user_properties
ORDER BY
    event_timestamp DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Results:

[image: Image of flatten flatten table]

---

If anyone could help with this approach or knows BigQuery better than myself and a simple method to flatten the data from GA then I would really appreciate your help.

---

### TEMP EDITS:

Here is the code that I have tried in BigQuery:

```sql
-- standardSQL
WITH data1 AS (
    SELECT GENERATE_UUID() AS row_id, event_params, user_properties
    FROM `yepic-2021.analytics_264796885.events_intraday_*`
),
data2 AS (
    SELECT *, GENERATE_ARRAY(1, GREATEST(ARRAY_LENGTH(event_params), ARRAY_LENGTH(user_properties))) ordinals
    FROM data1
)
SELECT row_id, event_params[SAFE_ORDINAL(o)] event_params, user_properties[SAFE_ORDINAL(o)] user_properties
FROM data2, UNNEST(ordinals) o
```

Results:

[image: BigQuery Answer Results]

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach almost works, except two issues:

- you need to use `SAFE_OFFSET` to avoid errors
- it only works if `event_params` has more elements than `user_properties`, otherwise you miss some user properties.

Let's fix it. To allow for either column to be bigger, we'll take largest of the array length, and use it for array index generation. Then we use `SAFE_ORDINAL` (`SAFE_OFFSET` works too):

```
-- sample input data, id and two two repeated fields x and y.
with data as (
    select 1 id, [1,2,3] x, ['a', 'b'] y 
    union all
    select 2 id, [4,5] x, ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f'] y
), 
-- let's add the ordinals arrays, taking length of longer array.
data2 as (
    select *, 
      generate_array(1, greatest(array_length(x), array_length(y))) ordinals
    from data
)
select id, x[safe_ordinal(o)] x, y[safe_ordinal(o)] y
from data2, unnest(ordinals) o
```

The result

```
id  x       y
-------------
1   1       a
1   2       b
1   3       null
2   4       c
2   5       d
2   null    e
2   null    f
```

**Update**

This works if the repeated fields are simple. If the repeated field is a RECORD, you get a NULL RECORD. You might want to have a RECORD with NULL leaf values instead, for this use an expression like

```
coalesce(x[safe_ordinal(o)], struct<a int64, b int64>(null, null)) x
```

Or to really fully flatten the output table, and only get leaf fields, without any traces of RECORD field, just extract the leaf fields as another step:

```
-- sample input data, id and two two repeated fields x and y.
with data as (
    select 1 id, [struct<a int64, b int64>(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)] x, ['a', 'b'] y 
    union all
    select 2 id, [struct<a int64, b int64>(7, 8), (9, 10)] x, ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f'] y
), 
data2 as (
  select id, x[safe_ordinal(o)] x, y[safe_ordinal(o)] y
  from data, unnest( generate_array(1, greatest(array_length(x), array_length(y)))) o
)
select id, x.a a, x.b b, y 
from data2
```

**Last note**

So we have a solution, but I have to warn that it is really rare that kind of flattening makes sense. In your case, there is no connection between i-th item in `user_properties` and i-th item in `event_params`. Here the first `user_properties` is paired to the first `event_params`, but it is equally related to any of them. They are just two independent lists, and flattening them this way is pretty arbitrary.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and tying out your code in BigQuery goes give a great result. I understand that there is no connection between the i-th items in each column. They all connect to the specific event at some timestamp. Creating an id for the event is great and that helps to link them to right event and timestamp. If you have a better structure approach for the data then I would be happy to take that on. Unfortunately, I have tried the solution with my data and it's not producing the same output as yours. For my code I still get the repeated BigQuery view and not nulls.

Comment: I will edit my question just to show you what I'm getting

Comment: Yeah, there is a bit more work to flatten RECORDs, as you get NULL RECORD, instead of a RECORD with NULL leaf fields. I added couple ideas how to handle those.